# Registering a concrete type in Simple Injector and using it throws ActivationException

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I am using Simple Injector to register a concrete type in the container in a .NET Core console app (in `Program.cs`), but Simple Injector throws an exception on start up:

> The constructor of type Application contains the parameter with name 'configUpdater' and type ConfigUpdater, but ConfigUpdater is not registered. For ConfigUpdater to be resolved, it must be registered in the container. An implicit registration could not be made because Container.Options.ResolveUnregisteredConcreteTypes is set to 'false', which is now the default setting in v5. This disallows the container to construct this unregistered concrete type. For more information on why resolving unregistered concrete types is now disallowed by default, and what possible fixes you can apply, see https://simpleinjector.org/ructd

EDIT:
Adding a MRE example which throws the exception:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using NLog;
using SimpleInjector;

namespace MRE
{
    public static class Program
    {
        private static Container container;

        static Program()
        {
            container = new Container();

            container.Register<IApplication, Application>(Lifestyle.Singleton);
            var appSettings = new AppSettings();

            container.Register(
                typeof(AppSettings),
                () => appSettings,
                Lifestyle.Singleton
            );

            container.RegisterConditional(
                typeof(ILog),
                typeCtx => typeof(NLogProxy<>).MakeGenericType(typeCtx.Consumer.ImplementationType),
                Lifestyle.Singleton,
                predCtx => true
            );

            container.Register<IConfigUpdater, ConfigUpdater>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var application = container.GetInstance<IApplication>();
            application.RunAsync();
        }
    }

    public class AppSettings
    {
        public string ConnectionString { get; set; } = "DataSource=data.db";
    }

    public interface ILog
    {
        void Info(string message);
    }

    public class NLogProxy<T> : ILog
    {
        private static readonly NLog.ILogger Logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(T).FullName);

        public void Info(string message) => Logger.Log(LogLevel.Info, message);
    }

    public interface IApplication
    {
        Task RunAsync();
    }

    public class Application : IApplication
    {
        private readonly ILog logger;
        private readonly IConfigUpdater configUpdater;

        public Application(
            ILog logger,
            IConfigUpdater configUpdater
        )
        {
            this.logger = logger;
            this.configUpdater = configUpdater;
        }

        public Task RunAsync()
        {
            logger.Info("Running");
            configUpdater.DoTask();
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }

    public interface IConfigUpdater
    {
        Task DoTask();
    }

    public class ConfigUpdater : IConfigUpdater
    {
        private readonly AppSettings appSettings;
        private readonly ILog logger;

        public ConfigUpdater(
            AppSettings appSettings,
            ILog logger
        )
        {
            this.appSettings = appSettings;
            this.logger = logger;
        }

        public Task DoTask()
        {
            var connectionString = appSettings.ConnectionString;
            logger.Info(connectionString);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT #2:
With the help of the MRE, I discovered my issue was actually hiding behind the scenes. It was a issue with using `Lifestyle.Scoped` which for some reason was not the first exception thrown. Setting the default lifestyle to `AsyncScopedLifestyle` fixes it.

Comment: The `Application` constructor shouldn't take a concrete type, it should take an interface.

Comment: I get the same exception with injecting the interface

Comment: Does the exception message show other types that need to be registered?

Comment: @Neil, nope. Just that class / interface

Comment: Can you update your question and post a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), because with the currently given code and description, I find it hard to imagine what is going wrong. Best is to update the question and add a code example that shows a minimal (but complete) configuration that exhibits the problem you are experiencing. Try reproducing this inside the Main method of a stand-alone Console application with separate types and post both the body of the `Main` method and the type signatures (so interfaces, types, and their constructors).

Comment: Are all the interfaces mentioned in ConfigUpdater registered in  _container?

Comment: @Steven Added a MRE, in a single .NET Core console Program file.

Comment: @Neil Yes, there is only one container and they are registered

Comment: Where is IConfigUpdater registered in MRE?

Comment: @Neil Apologies, missed that. It's there now (with the exception too)

Comment: Hi @segmentation_fault, your update doesn't seem an MRE, because when I run it, I get a completely different error from what you are describing. The error I'm getting is: "To be able to use the Lifestyle.Scoped property, please ensure that the container is configured with a default scoped lifestyle by setting the Container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle property." Did you run your MRE?

Comment: Oh shoot, I ran it, got the exact exception then @Neil pointed out I didn't register it so I added it. But then I just ran it, saw an exception (didn't read it) and updated the MRE

Comment: When running your MRE with the `DefaultScopedLifestyle`, the following exception is thrown: "[Lifestyle Mismatch] Application (Singleton) depends on IConfigUpdater implemented by ConfigUpdater (Async Scoped). ... Please see https://simpleinjector.org/diagnostics how to fix problems and how to suppress individual warnings." Did you see this exception, inspect the message, and read [the documentation](https://simpleinjector.org/diagnostics) the message points to? If so, what are your remaining questions after reading the documentation?

Comment: @Steven, yes I got that exception too. I read the documentation, understood why the exception is happening and updated my code accordingly(made `Application` be `Scoped` and used a `using (AsyncScopedLifestyle.BeginScope(_container)`) statement and it's now working.

Comment: Good to hear...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of the MRE, I found that the actual error was to do with the default `Lifestyle` SimpleInjector was using. Adding the line:

```
container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new AsyncScopedLifestyle();
```

fixes the issue of this question.

As to why the Lifestyle exception wasn't thrown first, I don't know.